# Can find how to use replace with regex in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a table in Excel and one of its columns contains string of the type: 125j, 0j, 12j, etc.

I want the value of the cells (in this column) to be replace by the numbers (i.e. I want to drop the "j") using the VBA.  Here is what I have:

```
Dim reg As Object
Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
reg.IgnoreCase = True
reg.Pattern = "^[0-9]+"

If reg.test(Cells(i, 4).Value) Then
    Cells(i, 4).Value = reg.Execute(Cells(i, 4).Value)
End If
```

But it doesn't work, do anyone knows either how to crrect it or to obtain the same result from another command?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `.Execute` method is a `MatchCollection` object. You can use that explicitly:

```
Dim reg As Object
Dim allMatches As Object

Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
reg.IgnoreCase = True
reg.Pattern = "^[0-9]+"

If reg.test(cells(i, 4).Value) Then
    Set allMatches = reg.Execute(cells(i, 4).Value)
    cells(i, 4).Value = allMatches(0)
End If
```

Or implicitly:

```
    cells(i, 4).Value = reg.Execute(cells(i, 4).Value)(0)
```